# How to get last date table was modified

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to provide a date for an app to check for updates.
For this I need to get the last date some of my tables in my database were modified.

I was checking for the last updated record in the table like this:

```
MyTable.find(:first, :order => "updated_at DESC")
```

but then I notice, that if I delete a record, I will get the previous updated record, which will be "obsolete", I need to get the date where the last record was deleted or modified.

Is there a way to obtain this without having some sort of global variable keeping up all of the changes that are being made?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like the [Audited](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) gem.

Comment: From the description I think that gem only records changes to the model and not to the records... please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You really got me wondering the same thing now. They don't state it clearly in the documentation one way or another, but judging from their examples it really looks like they're doing it with the saved objects (or records).